# After using setData() method of LibXML in perl the data is not written out to the actual xml file

Tags: xml, perl, xml-serialization, xml-libxml

I have an issue with the setData method of libXML in perl. Here is my code snippet:

```
    print "\n Query: " , $query, "\n";  #Query
    my($exactNode) = $doc->findnodes($query);  #Finding the nodes who data needs to change
    print "\n Data: ", $exactNode->setData($finalString), "\n";  #Setting the data
```

After using the setData I used getData to retrieve the value. The value outputted by getData is the latest one but when I open the xml where this data should be set. The value is the old.

Please advise what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not too familiar with LibXML, but setData is documented to return nothing.  You probably have to call `setData()` and then retrieve it separately.

I also do not believe the LibXML will save changes for you.  You likely have to explicitly save the modified XML document, probably with `toFile`.  See [XML::LibXML::Document](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aDocument).

Comment: Yeah It worked. I used print $doc->toString and all the changes got printed to the main screen. Then using > operator, the changes got saved in the new file and not the input file.